# HTML Email won't stack for mobile Gmail, but stacks for all other mobile versions

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, html-email

I've spent the last few hours trying to troubleshoot the top portion of an email and I have no idea why it's not stacking for Gmail Android. So basically on all of the td's that contain the company logo, hyperlinks, and the Order Now button, I have the class name of .Stack on them.

I have a media query for max-width 480px for .Stack that sets it to display block and 100% width. For whatever reason it doesn't seem to be stacking for Gmail Mobile versions but stacks for iPhone's.

I am testing with Email on Acid. Anyone know if there's something I'm missing here? Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" CONTENT="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
<style type="text/css">
/*---------------------------- RESET STYLES ----------------------------*/
table, td {
    mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
    mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
}
.ExternalClass {
    width: 100%;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}
.yshortcuts, a .yshortcuts, a .yshortcuts:hover, a .yshortcuts:active, a .yshortcuts:focus {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
    color: inherit !important;
}
/*----- IOS LINKS FIX -----*/

a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
}
.appleIOSFix a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*----- Insert FONT code here -----*/
}
/*----- GMAIL SPECIFIC -----*/

u + .body .Gmail-hide {
    display: none;
}
u + .body .Gmail-show {
    display: block !important;
}

/*---------------------------- MOBILE TARGETING ----------------------------*/

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
/* TEMPLATE AND BASIC STYLES */

/*----- STRUCTURE -----*/
*[class=Container] {
    max-width: 600px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
*[class=Stack] {
    display: block !important;
    clear: both !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
*[class=TopCol] {
    display: table-header-group !important;
    clear: both !important;
}
*[class=BottomCol] {
    display: table-footer-group !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
*[class=MidCol] {
    display: table-row-group !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
*[class=RevStack] {
    display: table-cell !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
*[class=Fullwidth] {
    width: 100% !important;
}
*[class=Halfwidth] {
    width: 50% !important;
}
*[class=CenterTbl] {
    margin: auto !important;
}
/*----- CONTENT -----*/

*[class=Img] {
    max-width: 600px !important;
    height: auto !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
*[class=Origsize] {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
*[class=Halfsize] {
    width: 50% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
*[class=Hide] {
    display: none !important;
}
*[class=LeftAlign] {
    text-align: left !important;
}
*[class=CenterAlign] {
    text-align: center !important;
}
*[class=RightAlign] {
    text-align: right !important;
}
*[class=LetterCap] {
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
*[class=Headline] {
    font-size: 30px !important;
    line-height: 32px !important;
}
*[class=SubHdline] {
    font-size: 24px !important;
    line-height: 26px !important;
}
*[class=Body] {
    font-size: 15px !important;
    line-height: 18px !important;
}
*[class=Legal] {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    line-height: 12px !important;
}
*[class=WhiteLink] {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
*[class=DarkLink] {
    color: #000000 !important;
}
/* Insert ADDITIONAL STYLES here - IF REQUIRED */
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;" class="body" >

<table role="presentation" Width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><!--Begin CONTAINER-->
        
        <table role="presentation" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="Container">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <main>
                <!--Begin 1COLTBL-->
                <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#d52027">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" style="padding: 14px 0px 14px 0px;">
                        <!--Begin 3COLTBL-->
                        <table role="presentation" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#d52027">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td width="30" class="Stack"></td>
                              <td class="Stack" align="center">
                                <!--Begin IMGSML-->
                                <div><img role="presentation" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496200186974-4293800e2c20?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3432&q=80" width="140" height="79" style="vertical-align: bottom;" border="0"></div>
                                <!--End IMGSML-->
                              </td>
                              <td width="100" class="Stack">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td class="Stack" align="center" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-transform: uppercase; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Locations</a></td>
                              <td class="Stack" width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td class="Stack" align="center" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-transform: uppercase; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">Menu</a></td>
                              <td class="Stack" width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                              <td class="Stack" align="center" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
                                <!--Begin BTNAMPRI-->
                                  <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="ordernowbutton" style="-moz-border-radius: 50px; -webkit-border-radius: 50px; border-radius: 50px; padding: 10px 16px 10px 16px;"><div><a href="#" target="_blank" class="ordernowtext" style="color: #d52027; display: inline-block; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; white-space: nowrap; text-transform: uppercase;" class="Fullwidth">Order Now</a></div></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                  <!--End BTNAMPRI--->
                              </td>
                              <td class="Stack" width="30"></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <!--End 3COLTBL-->
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <!--End 1COLTBL-->

              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <!--End CONTAINER--></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gmail will remove the entire `<style>` block if it finds something that it disapproves of in there.

It disapproves of `*[class=Legal]` and similar constructions. This may have been necessary in the past for Yahoo, but is no longer. So go ahead and change these to the normal format, i.e. `.Legal`.

If that doesn't work, put the mobile styles in their own `<style>` block and try again. There may be something else it doesn't like.

The other thing to know is that there are different versions of Gmail. So if you're looking at a Gmail that uses IMAP/POP, that doesn't support `<head>` anything--it gets stripped out entirely. So you have to rely only on inline code for that. So the inline code should already be responsive.